# Rails.application.credentials.dig is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my **credentials.yml**

```
development:
  a:
    b:
      c:
        d: http://test.com
```

```
> Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :a,:b,:c,:d) + "service"
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Anyone can help me to fix it?

Comment: what version of rails do you use ?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use plain text credentials if you're using **Rails 5.2 or newer**.

There's only `credentials.yml.enc` instead of `credentials.yml`

`credentials.yml.enc` is an encrypted file which store the credentials.

To add credentials, run `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`
and then add your credentials to editor.

After they are saved, `Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :a,:b,:c,:d)` should return correct value.